# HTML form click in Objective C - like using mechanize in Python

Tags: python, objective-c, forms, mechanize

I have this code in Python that was quite simple to do with mechanize to just go into a URL and click the submit button:

```
from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen, urljoin

response = urlopen("http://www.somesite.com/somepage")
forms = ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
form = forms[0]

print urlopen(form.click()).read()
```

Now the question is:  Is there any library/simple method to do this in Objective-C?

I've seen some more or less of similar examples with NSURL that where quite big, but since I'll be doing this to a bunch of diferent sites, it doesn't look like a simple thing to go torugh some dozens of code lines to each one of them and debug everything if there is some easy way like with mechanize.

Regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this site: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
It is not actually what you want, but you can send the POST/GET values to the form action page.

if you have a page http://test.com/form.php with following form:

```
<form name="login" method="POST" action="action.php">
    <input name="username"><br />
    <input name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

you can use this code, to perform this form.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com/action.php];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"Admin" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"1234" forKey:@"password"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: Thanks jussi. This seems a really handy library and I'll sure check it for more advanced stuff. But I didn't get how to do what I want by looking arround the documentation of this ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Edited my answer and provided some Code

Comment: Hi jussi. Thank you very much again.
But now I see my error - sorry, I'm completely new at this, I just managed to do it in Python because it was easy, but I didn't understand what was going on.
What I'm trying to give input to, is not a normal form, that's an javascript form. That's why the POST method with NSURLConnection doesn't seem to work.

I didn't give a try to your exemple yet, does it work with javascript?

Comment: Hi jussi. It wasn't needed after all. The javascript was just to validate the form not to process the output. I used some Google Chrome utility to transform the GET's in POST's and I got some link that bypassed that.
My problem is now solved - at least for this site.
Thank you !